# Facebook re-authentication

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm using PHP SDK to authentication and requesting permissions.

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '7xxx349xx',
  'secret' => 'x0b360034c9exxxx4f',
  'cookie' => true
));
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'publish_actions, read_friendlists',
  'redirect_uri' => 'example.com',
);

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$usertoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
  header("Location: xxx.php");
}
if(!$user) {
  //$statusUrl = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl();
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}
```

It works well but if user delete app in privacy settings and try to login again I have errors:

> CSRF state token does not match one provided.
>   OR
>   OAuthException: Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application [APPID]

How to fix it? I need additional code?

Thanks for help